# Importing unittest - Test Module not found

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, module, importerror

I'm new to Python and I'm currently trying to write a simple unit test with a module called test_account, but immediately the module is not identified:

```
ImportError: No module named test_account
```

When I run:

```
 python -m unittest test_account
```

This is the Unit Test:

```
import unittest
from python_challenge import MarketSegment

class TestUniqueSegmentAccounts(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_account(self):
        self.isInstance(add_account(acc1, MarketSegment('Consumer Goods', [acc1, acc2])))
```

This is what the class looks like:

```
class MarketSegment(object):
    def __init__(self, name, accounts=None):
        self.name = name
        self._accounts = []

        if accounts:
            self._accounts.extend(accounts)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{self.name}".format(self=self)

    def add_account(self, account):
        if account in self._accounts:

            raise ValueError ('Accounts cannot be assigned to the same Market Segment more than once.') 

        else:
            self._accounts.append(account)
            account.set_market_segments(self)
            return self._accounts
```

**Update: I've tried adding __ init __ .py files and intalling pytest but neither were useful. I've found that in .../unittest/__ main __.py the module = None

```
<module> main(module=None)
```

Comment: what is `python_challenge` in `from python_challenge import MarketSegment`

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my typo: python_challenge is the name of the file where my classes are

Comment: It would help if you describe your folder structure and from where you try to run the tests. It seems that you are running them from a folder explicitly created to hold all your tests. If that's the case you might find [this article on the python-guide website](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/#test-suite) useful.